# How to calculate maximum connection limit on mysql

Tags: mysql

I am trying to optimize MySQL server which having following parameters:
RAM - 8G
cores - 4
How can I calculate the number of connection a server can be served based on RAM size, the number of cores?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

this had already answered on https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/1229/how-do-you-calculate-mysql-max-connections-variable
Results of SHOW VARIABLES LIKE '%buffer%'; gives in bytes.